# SQL Server - Logical Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
Id INT/PK
UserId INT/FK
CreatedDate DATETIME
ActivityMarker INT/FK
```

The table can be written to (incl. record updates) and deleted from (e.g. today I can delete a record from 1/1/2010). The CreatedDate contains the date the record was created. ActivityMarker and UserId can be updated.

What I need to do is keep a historical record of how many records, daily, for a given UserId X, had ActivityMarker Y. I need this information to chart for a user how many items for a given marker they had across time.

I understand that the current table structure doesn't support this kind of historical information; once somebody changes the value of ActivitiyMarker or UserId, the previous value is gone forever, and I don't know when the change happened either.

Can someone suggest the best way to keep this information so I can, in the end, get the count of records for a given UserId and ActivityMarker as it was on a specific day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a record of the changes by using effective dating.

or

Use a trigger to audit to another table

or

Take a look at SQL 2008 audit feature (may have something for you in there, but I'm not sure it will be in a friendly feature).

Effective dating is where you keep all your records and mark one as being the currently active one either through some kind of date logic or a flag.  Here is an article explaining the concept - http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/ .

Auditing with triggers is fairly common and you should be able to find loads of info about it.

SQL Audit is a new feature in 2008 - looks like it dumps interactions on an object to a log - might just store t-sql statements and userid, not actual values of the columns.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about your 'effective dating' suggestion? How does this help?

Comment: You'll find the record with the most recent effective date which is not in the future using a group by statement to get records for that person.  Triggers can also be used to update a flag on the active record to make querying easier - so you don't have to do the whole group by with max(effective_date) every time you need to query the darn table.

Comment: Keep in mind that your table will grow large and that the audit table may be a better choice if you need to keep this table small.  Of course, the audit trigger will also use resources, but only during an insert/update.

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a table like this

```
Id INT/PK   -- alternately UserId + Rundate could be the PK
UserId INT/FK
RunDate DATETIME
AMCount INT
```

Then run daily:

```
INSERT INTO HistoricalActivityMarkers( UserId, RunDate, AMCount)
   SELECT UserId, GETDATE(), count(*)
   FROM ActivityMarkerTbl
   GROUP BY UserId, GETDATE()
```

Since you only want a daily record, there is no need for triggers, which would record every change, and would also fail to give you a daily record if a cahnge isn't made at least once a day.

Comment: So I would execute your INSERT at the end of each day?

Comment: Yes.  It will add one row for each user into the HistoricalActivityMarkers table (give it a better name)

Answer (score 0):

How about writing snapshots of the records to a history table?  If you are working right in SQL Server you could use triggers.  If you are working w/ an ORM tool, some have the ability to intercept changes.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to do this with triggers please?

Comment: You would create a trigger on insert/update for the table.  In this trigger insert all the field (or just changed ones for updates if you want) into a history table along with a timestamp.